# How to change ID of an attachment in wp_posts and its related tables correctly?

Tags: plugins, posts, images, post-meta, attachments

I have two posts in my `wp_posts` table `where post_type='attachment'`
The picture below shows the records related to those in `wp_postmeta` table

[image]

I need to change the IDs of those files. What I am doing is:

```
update wp_posts 
set ID = ID + 10000 
where ID in (3143,3144); 


update wp_postmeta set post_id = post_id + 10000,
                       meta_id = meta_id + 100000
where post_id in (3143,3144);
```

When I do that, I am losing the images! I don't see it under "Media" section in `wp-admin`. In the webpage, they are not shown either. If I go: /wp-admin/upload.php?item=13143, it also does not come up. Only when I go to the link in the "guid" field of the related record at wp_posts, I see the image.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your query looks good and seems workning. I've made a test on my database and the image remained visible in the media library after the ID change. Maybe there was already other posts existing with that IDs